# Does the Mermin-Wagner theorem forbid superconductivity in the 2D Hubbard-Model?

Tags: solid-state-physics, phase-transition, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking

> "In the 2D Hubbard model (two spatial dimensions) the Mermin-Wagner theorem does not allow a phase transition."

I am quite illiterate concerning this theorem and hearsay. Does the theorem apply to a superconducting transition as well? References that justify its applicability are welcome.

Comment: If by 2D you mean two spatial dimensions, then Mermin-Wagner theorem allows spontaneous continuous symmetry breaking at zero temperature, but at finite temperature there is only algebraic long-range order. In one spatial dimension, even at $T=0$ there is no long-range-ordered superconductivity, only algebraic ones.

Comment: Yes, i mean 2D. I can educate myself of course but what is algebraic/non-algebraic long range order? Do you have references? I would be interested especially in a comprehensive argument, why the theorem applies to SC as well. So far i war only aware of its application to magnetic phase transitions.

Comment: Instead of saying some order parameter has a finite expectation value, a better way to describe spontaneous symmetry breaking is to look at the correlation function of order parameters, and algebraic long-range order just means the correlation function decays as a power-law with distance.

Comment: So do i understand correctly that you're saying that the Mermin-Wagner theorem does not exclude superconductivity in the 2D hubbard model as long as the correlation function of the order parameter decays as a power law ,i.e. it does not diverge? Or is it better to call that something like superconducting fluctuations?

Comment: This is a generic feature of SSB in 2D. Only at $T=0$ (the ground state), there is true long-range order. When $T>0$ it always becomes algebraic.

Comment: See [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/144026/89797), [Wikipedia on Ginzburg–Landau theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory), or (if you have access) [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003491604001046) for a discussion of the complex order parameter in superconductors.

Comment: Superconductivity is described by a complex order parameter $\Psi$ (sometimes thought of as a macroscopic wavefunction). Complex numbers have both magnitude and phase, and so are equivalent to two-component vectors. The [Mermin–Wagner(–Hohenberg) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem) says that, in two spatial dimensions at nonzero temperature, there can be no symmetry-breaking transition where a continuous symmetry is broken. The symmetry broken in a superconductor is phase-rotation symmetry: a nonzero $\Psi$ implies a certain complex phase.